# How to set default file browse location with firefox addon sdk

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, gecko

Im new Firefox addon programming.
I want set default file browse location with firefox addon sdk.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Share the code you're using right now then more people can help you out. (im non-sdk dev, but if you show me the code i can still help you out)

Comment: Sorry, It's just my idea. I don't have code.

Comment: So you want to open a file browser? So they can select a file? Or select a folder? something like that?

Comment: I want set default file browser location like download folder location. When i clicked file input they open exactly my folder i set before

Answer (score 2):

open scratchpad copy and paste this:

```
const nsIFilePicker = Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker;

var fp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"]
               .createInstance(nsIFilePicker);
var startDir = FileUtils.File('C:\\');
fp.displayDirectory = startDir;

fp.init(window, "Dialog Title", nsIFilePicker.modeOpen);
fp.appendFilters(nsIFilePicker.filterAll | nsIFilePicker.filterText);

var rv = fp.show();
if (rv == nsIFilePicker.returnOK || rv == nsIFilePicker.returnReplace) {
  var file = fp.file;
  // Get the path as string. Note that you usually won't 
  // need to work with the string paths.
  var path = fp.file.path;
  // work with returned nsILocalFile...
}
```

if thats what you want let me know, then ill put it in a default location

Comment: What do you mean new format? Can you post what you convert to so I can learn. Thx

Comment: var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
var fp = Cc["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"]
               .createInstance(Ci.nsIFilePicker);

Comment: ah i see,, did it work out for you, were you able to set default path to open?

Comment: We have 100 forms and more in my app. One form browse one folder. That is hard for users to remember all location. This solution can storage location folder to data and set default  before users click input file button. I will check it tonight and vote for you. thank you so much. I'm from Viet Nam. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: i added the code that makes it start in a default location. the code is: `var startDir = FileUtils.File('C:\\'); fp.displayDirectory = startDir;`